# Including Angle Brackets In Pre Sections

Tags: code, pre

I am attempting to post some java code between pre tags but the angel brackets get removed.  For example:

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> featureCounts;
```

becomes

```
private HashMap> featureCounts;
```

Is there a way I can render the actual code?   Also I am not a php developer or a wordpress expert by any means, so modifying the underlying php would be less preferred as a solution. Is there a way I can do this just using the editor?

Comment: If you don't mind a wiki-like syntax, you might give [BlogText](http://blogtext.mayastudios.com/) a try. I wrote this plugin (partially) to solve exactly your problem (as I'm a developer myself).

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding your code to a string, then using the php function [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
$thecode = "private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> featureCounts;\n";
$thecode.= "2nd line of code\n";
$thecode.= "3rd line of code\n";
$thecode.= "4th line of code\n";
```

the `trim()` function will remove any whitespace at the start & end of the string.

```
<pre><?php echo trim(htmlspecialchars($thecode));?></pre>
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to display them in a page or a post, you could try using their character entities.  In the Text view in the editor, type `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>`.

So, for instance, in your editor's Text view (not the Visual mode), you'd type:

```
<pre>
private HashMap&lt;String, HashMap&lt;String, Integer&gt;&gt; featureCounts;
</pre>
```

And that should do it.